# Getting different feeds from one URL

Tags: php, youtube-api

i am trying to get some data(stats) from a specific YouTube channel. For this i am using following URL:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels/rX3yH7nFEQq49lQGVk2Iqg?v=2

When i enter this URL directly into FireFox Addressbar i get the result i am looking for. BUT
if i open the exact same URL with:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels/rX3yH7nFEQq49lQGVk2Iqg?v=2');
```

i get a completly different result(using print_r($data))!

Is there an explanation for this? Are i am doing something wrong? Is there something missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The most useful information about a channel will actually come from the /users/ service, not the /channels/.

You could also add in `alt=json`, unless you *really* like parsing XML instead of working with JSON.

Finally, the "correct" form for a channel id has a `UC` prefix, though v2 supports channel ids without the prefix as well.

Putting that all together gives you https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCrX3yH7nFEQq49lQGVk2Iqg?v=2&alt=json

(leave out `alt=json` to work with `simplexml_load_file()`)